# On the distribution of the primes / the probability of a false positive from Miller-Rabin

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

This is my second question today about Miller-Rabin; this should be it for a while :).

Assume we're using Miller-Rabin to test whether $n$ is prime. Let $T_k$ be the event that $n$ passes $k$ rounds of the test, and let $C_n$ be the event that $n$ is composite. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), for example, tells us that $P(T_k | C_n)\le 4^{-k}$. However, what is more interesting is the probability of a false positive, $P(C_n | T_k)$. Using Bayes's theorem, we get

$$P(C_n | T_k) = \frac{P(T_k | C_n)P(C_n)}{P(T_k | C_n)P(C_n)+P(T_k | C_n^\prime)P(C_n^\prime)}$$

I'd like to find an upper bound for this, but one that doesn't require, say, [18 pages](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper88.pdf) to explain. Specifically, I'd like to make the above result about $P(T_k|C_n)$ the most exotic one that I use. To do so, I started by finding numerators that are at least as large as the one above and denominators that are no larger that the one above — without deviating *too* much, of course.

As $n$ gets larger, primes become sparser, and so it would seem we don't lose too much by swapping out $P(C_n)$ for $1$. While we're at it, let's just drop the first term in the denominator. Finally, Miller-Rabin never returns a false negative, so $P(T_k |C_n^\prime) = 1$. This gives us

$$P(C_n | T_k) \le \frac{1}{4^kP(C_n^\prime)}$$

I feel *pretty* good about everything so far.  So what about $P(C_n^\prime)$? Assuming the primes are uniformly distributed — which I'm not sure I should assume —

$$P(C_n^\prime) = \frac{\pi(n)}{n} = \frac{\pi(n)}{n}\cdot \frac{\log n}{\log n} \to \frac{1}{\log n},$$

an expression that, despite my aforementioned reservations, is corroborated by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) (see second graf of intro). Thus,

$$P(C_n | T_k) \stackrel{\text{k.s.}}{\le} \frac{\log n}{4^k}, $$

where $\text{k.s.}$ stands for the relation kinda sorta being true.

Now, I'm trying to ascertain whether $\pi(n) \ge n/\log n$ for all large enough $n$.  (I've read that $\text{li}(n)$ is not bounded below by $\pi(n)$, which is one reason, though not the primary one, that I'm not looking at it.) If it is, then I think the inequality above really does hold.  So the question is:  Is $\pi(n) \ge n/\log n$ for all large enough $n$?  And if it is, does my upper bound hold?

Even if all that checks out, there's still this assumption the distribution of the primes.  To what extent is their distribution understood?  Lacking complete information, how can one proceed?

Finally, if for whatever reason (...) what I wrote is *not* true, can anything be salvaged?  Again, I'm looking for simplicity, not tightness.  For example, the above suggests that, if $n \sim 10^{100}$, and if we want $P(C_n | T_k) \le 10^{-2}$, it suffices to have $k\ge8$; from what I can make out from the above article, I'm assuming that $k=8$ actually yields a much smaller probability of error.